# Tags not found in neovim, but work in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, neovim

I have a `tags` file which is being generated and placed in my project's directory and `set tags=./tags,tags;/` placed in my `init.vim` (*edit: this was to ensure that the configuration is the same across both editors*)

The crazy thing is that, when looking for tags in neovim (v0.1.7), nothing is found, however tagbar (majutsushi/tagbar) seems to find these tags correctly. Furthermore, I have set tags to point directly to the tag file (`set tags=/home/<me/project/>tags`) with no change in outcome. When I perform the same steps in vim (v8.0, 2016 Sep 12) these tags are found correctly.

Does neovim handle ctags in a different way from vim or am I missing something simple?

Thanks

*EDIT:*

@Justin M. Keyes is correct in the behavior of vim and neovim. I failed to ask the vague question of "why is my system broken" since there was not a whole lot to go on, but the answer to this, for me, was found here:

> [Why can't vim see the tags file, despite being in the same directory?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/why-cant-vim-see-the-tags-file-despite-being-in-the-same-directory) - Vi and Vim Exchange (beta)

In my case the [vim-scripts/gitignore](https://github.com/vim-scripts/gitignore) plugin was adding patterns to my `wildignore` variable which obscured my editor from finding my tags file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set tags=./tags,tags;/` is an unsual choice. As mentioned at `:help 'tags'`, the default in nvim is:

```
'tags' 'tag'            string  (default "./tags;,tags")
```

Try *not* setting the 'tags' option, use the default instead.

> when looking for tags in neovim (v0.1.7), nothing is found, however tagbar (majutsushi/tagbar) seems to find these tags correctly

It's not unlikely that tagbar looks in places other than what is specified by the 'tags' option.

> Does neovim handle ctags in a different way from vim

No, only the default changed.